# Order in which classLoader will load classes in this scenario

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader, lombok, eclipse-classpath

I added `lombok` to my java project in `eclipse`. It required me to add the last two lines in `eclipse.ini` file as `vmargs`.

```
-showlocation
-vm
/home/$USER/JavaSE8/jdk1.8/bin/java
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms500m
-Xmx2g
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=''
-javaagent:/home/$USER/eclipse/4.4-luna-SR2/lombok.jar
-Xbootclasspath/a:/home/$USER/eclipse/4.4-luna-SR2/lombok.jar
```

I have also added `lombok.jar` in `libraries` (Project -> Properties -> Libraries) and also moved `lombok.jar` to the topmost level in  Order and Export tab (Project -> Properties -> Order and Export) in eclipse and JRE System Library (rt.jar, resources.jar, etc.) all are below `lombok.jar`. I'm confused about the order in which `lombok` main class will be loaded as :

1. When `eclipse` is launched,  the `Bootstrap` classloader should load all JDK classes in directory of JRE. (But since I have moved `lombok.jar` up in Order and Export, above JRE system libraries, will rt.jar be loaded after `lombok.jar`. Mostly No? because bootstrap libraries should always be loaded first no matter WHAT !)
2. Since we also redefined the `bootstrap classpath` using -XBootstrapClasspath option, lombok.jar will be loaded by `Bootstrap Classloader`.
3. After that `Extensions classloader` loads the classes in lib\ext directory of the JRE.
4. Then `System-Classpath classloader` loads all classes and jars specified by the CLASSPATH environment variable (Does this loading takes into account the `Order and Export` order of libraries?)

Please correct me if I'm wrongly interpreting things here as I'm just newbie trying to understand the ClassLoading maze.

Comment: @kdgregory  Can you please answer this question?

Comment: @Juned Ahsan Can you please answer this question ?

Comment: FYI: Since at least version 1.16.4, it is no longer necessary to add `lombok.jar` to the bootclasspath at all. You only need to add the jar as an agent.

Comment: @RoelSpilker Thanks for the info. Yes Lombok 1.16.x works by just adding jar as agent. I just want to know when do you add a jar as an agent and to bootclasspath?

Answer (score 0):

You often mention the "order and export". I assume you mean the same named tab in the project classpath dialog. As far as I know this concerns only the visibility of the projects library for other projects which depend on this project. It has nothing to do how eclipse itself is bootstrapped.

Comment: I tested what you wrote about about visibility of projects library for other projects which depend on this project. So I have 2 , say A & B projects to which I have added lombok.jar as libraries. Also A is dependent on B. In both A & B, I have used Lombok. I removed lombok.jar from B's libraries . Now the lombok annotations in B were shown with red lines (in eclipse).

Comment: It seems you interchanged the order. If A is dependant on B as you write, then remove the jar from project A (and not from B) and adjust the build path of project B to show the export of the library.